# How to create a copy of a draggable group of widgets by clicking a button

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to make a custom widget that can be duplicated if I click "add" button and can be dragged and dropped from one place to another place. In the code below, I can only set one group to be draggable, while the other cannot be moved. I also tried to create a new buttongroup by calling it inside the add_button function, but it seems it doesn't work. How could I implement this functionality? Please help.

Here is the mainfile.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from module_test import Ui_MainWindow
from mod_widgets import DragGroup,button_group

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*arg,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg,**kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self._add_counter = 0
        self.ui.buttons = button_group(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.buttons.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_button)
        self.ui.buttons2 = button_group(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.ui.buttons2.groupBox.move(50,50)
        self.show()
        
    def add_button(self):
        self._add_counter += 1
        print(self._add_counter)
        #Add another button_group
        #self.ui.buttons2 = button_group(self.ui.centralwidget)
        #self.ui.buttons2.groupBox.move(50,50)
    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()
        
    def dropEvent(self, e):
        pos = e.pos()
        #How to make both buttons can move independently?
        self.ui.buttons.move(pos)
        print(pos)
        e.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()
          
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the file created by QtDesigner module_test.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(798, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setAcceptDrops(True)


        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 798, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is my custom widget class mod_widgets.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class DragGroup(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
            mime =QtCore.QMimeData()
            drag.setMimeData(mime)
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
            self.render(pixmap)
            drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
            drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
            
#Create a independent Widgets class for each module 
class button_group(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.groupBox = DragGroup(self)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 211, 151))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 110, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.groupBox.setTitle("Test module")
        self.pushButton.setText("Add")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("Remove")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("Remove")
```

[Draggable group of widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dfiy.png)

Comment: `self.ui.buttons.move(pos)` will obviously always move the first group box. You could theoretically use the `event.source()` to get the groupbox that originated the drag event, and *assuming that it always has the same object structure*, move the parent: `e.source().parent().move(pos)`. The reality is that the `button_group` class doesn't make a lot of sense, just use `DragGroup` and add the buttons inside it, in this way you can directly access the correct source using a more appropriate `e.source().move(pos)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! In addition to your comment, for the add_button, I added self.ui.buttons2.show(), after that everything works well. Thanks!!